# Securing MongoDB 5.0 on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: mongodb

I have a fresh install of MongDB 5.0 on Ubunutu 20.04 and I am trying to configure basic root (admin) user access control [according to documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/#std-label-create-user-admin) and, of course, it just doesn't work on the very first command.  :-/

The very first instruction says that I need to run `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb` as the mongodb user, which on Ubuntu 20.04 by default is `mongdb`

So I have run:

`runuser -u mongodb -- "mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb"` (double quotes)

-permission denied

`runuser -u mongodb -- 'mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb'` (single quotes)

-permission denied

`runuser -u mongodb -- mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb` (no quotes)

-fails to connect, output below:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.566+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.567+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.567+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.568+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.570+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.571+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":23994,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"test.example.test"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.571+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.571+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.571+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"port":27017},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb"}}}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.571+08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.571+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":989}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T18:28:50.571+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting the above failure?

**UPDATE:**

On a hunch, I ran `chown mongodb:mongo /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` and that solved the permissions problem.

Now I get:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.471+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.473+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.473+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.474+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.475+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.476+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.476+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.476+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.476+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":48003,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"test.pragmaticprodigy.test"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.476+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.476+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.476+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"port":27017},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.478+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-27T19:18:45.479+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

An already in use exception... hhmmm

Answer (score 0):

For any other complete mongodb noob's like myself who just want to secure your mongodb admin user, so that you can actually follow tutorials & courses without your db getting hacked... This answer is for you:

1.) if you can't get a basic connection to the db by running `runuser -u mongodb -- mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

my hunch above was correct, but incomplete.  You need to run:

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323247/5180608

From there, run `systemctl restart mongod`

Now you should be able to execute `mongosh --port 27017` to connect to mongodb and then follow these instructions to complete setting up an admin user and password.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/

If you have connection issues, you may need to edit `/etc/mongod.conf` :

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: your-host-ip -OR- 127.0.0.1
```

As of 5.0 bindIp, must be a single value.